# correct fastener for drywall over plywood

Tags: drywall, plywood, drywall-anchor, fastener

I'm trying to install mirror brackets into my wall for a lightweight frameless wall mirror (58" x 16").

My attempt at using a hollow wall anchor (Hillman 1/8" DXS drive wall anchor) didn't work very well.
The drywall appears to be 3/8" thick, and directly behind it is some plywood that appears to be fairly thin too.
The anchor just chewed up the drywall leaving a 3/4" diameter hole.

What's the correct fastener to use here?

[image]

Comment: upon closer inspection, this might be plaster, not drywall

Comment: That looks like plaster and lath... you may be able to screw directly into the lath, with drywall screws, if the mirror is one of those light weight door mirrors.

Answer (score 1):

Use a molly bolt, sometimes called a toggle bolt.  They can be found and any hardware store.  The butterfly end opens up on the other side of the wall material.  When it is drawn tight it is a very good and strong fastener. While you are at the hardware store pick up a small can of spackel to be used to fill the seen portion of he fastened hole.

Comment: Will I need to drill a hole through both the drywall and plywood to insert the toggle bolt? Is there a specific length of toggle bolt I'll need?

Answer (score 0):

The plywood itself should be plenty strong, no *anchor* needed. Just use the thickest screw that  the brackets can accommodate and drill appropriate pilot holes.